# How to get rid of default blank space from HTML select control?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, dropdown, html-select

If I use simple HTML select control:

```html
<div>
  <select name="pets" id="pet-select">
      <option value="">-- Choose a pet --</option>
      <option value="dog">Dog</option>
      <option value="cat">Cat</option>
      <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
      <option value="parrot">Parrot</option>
      <option value="spider">Spider</option>
      <option value="goldfish">Goldfish</option>
  </select>
 </div>
<div>
 This is a page content below the select box!
</div>
```

in the result, there is a blank space on the right side of the items and below the last item, like this:

[image]

Are there any HTML/CSS tricks that can get rid of this space? By doing so, the div element below should stay in the position as it is now. The control should act as drop-down as it is now.

**EDIT 1:** based on the comment below, I tried to apply the styling:

```css
.select-css {
 display: block;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #444;
 line-height: 1.3;
 padding: .6em 1.4em .5em .8em;
 width: 400px;
 max-width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 border: 1px solid #aaa;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.04);
 border-radius: .5em;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
 background-color: #fff;
 background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23007CB2%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E'),
   linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
 background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
 background-position: right .7em top 50%, 0 0;
 background-size: .65em auto, 100%;
}
.select-css::-ms-expand {
 display: none;
}
.select-css:hover {
 border-color: #888;
}
.select-css:focus {
 border-color: #aaa;
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px rgba(59, 153, 252, .7);
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px -moz-mac-focusring;
 color: #222;
 outline: none;
}
.select-css option {
 font-weight:normal;
}

/* Support for rtl text, explicit support for Arabic and Hebrew */
*[dir="rtl"] .select-css, :root:lang(ar) .select-css, :root:lang(iw) .select-css {
 background-position: left .7em top 50%, 0 0;
 padding: .6em .8em .5em 1.4em;
}

/* Disabled styles */
.select-css:disabled, .select-css[aria-disabled=true] {
 color: graytext;
 background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22graytext%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E'),
   linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
}
.select-css:disabled:hover, .select-css[aria-disabled=true] {
 border-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
    <div>
      <select class="select-css">
        <option>This is a native select element</option>
        <option>Apples</option>
        <option>Bananas</option>
        <option>Grapes</option>
        <option>Oranges</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    <div>
     This is a page content below the select box!
    </div>
```

but the issue still remains: 
[image]

Comment: `<select>` has always been extremely hard to style reliably; browsers can vary a lot.

Comment: Speaking of CSS tricks: https://css-tricks.com/styling-a-select-like-its-2019/

Comment: @Pointy see the **Edit 1**